# VR Camera on the floor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm having an issue with my first project in Unity. It's about an architectural design, and the VR action is used to walk through the house. For this reason, I have used an look walk script >

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class VRLookWalk : MonoBehaviour
 {

     public Transform vrCamera;
     public float toggleAngle = 30.0f;
     public float speed = 3.0f;
     public bool moveForward;

     private CharacterController cc;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start()
     {
         cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (vrCamera.eulerAngles.x >= toggleAngle && vrCamera.eulerAngles.x < 90.0f)
         {
             moveForward = true;
         }
         else
         {
             moveForward = false;
         }

         if (moveForward )
         {
             Vector3 forward = vrCamera.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

             cc.SimpleMove(forward * speed);
         }
     }
 }
```

Everything is fine at the beginning, but when you need to advance, the camera is closer to the floor and you see everything from this view. I would like to see things in an human view. Could you provide me suggestions to try to fix it? Thanks in advance!

This is how I see the camera on the floor when I test it

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use the forward direction of the camera since it might point downwards if you are looking down. I'ld rather make the camera a child of some player object and move that instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @derHugo. Let me show you how the camera is set up > https://imgur.com/inJdnd1 - do you have any other suggestion?